# When are environment variables evaluated for docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I want to clarify my understanding of the docker compose environment is correct.

```
version: "3"
services:
  my-great-service: 
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - MY_VARIABLE=${MY_VARIABLE:-}
    image:
      my-great-service
```

If I run `docker-compose build my-great-service` in shell A, the env var MY_VARIABLE will be set of the value of MY_VARIABLE in shell A, and can be access within the dockerfile.

However, if I then run the docker image, the env variable will not be available at run time?

Comment: "if I then run the docker image" -- how exactly? Also, what is the relation to "shell A"?